# How to install airflow?

Tags: ubuntu, pip, airflow

I seem to be doing sth. wrong.

https://pythonhosted.org/airflow/start.html

```
$ export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow
$ pip install apache-airflow
Requirement already satisfied
$ airflow initdb
airflow: Command not found
```

> python --version
>   Python 2.7.10

It's weird - the installation seemed to have worked fine (with some warnings - nothing serious) saying: airflow, flask, etc. successfully installed. But even after restarting the PC (Ubuntu 15.10) airflow seems not to be a command.

Comment: can you do: `locate airflow` and run the command with the full path.

Comment: 'pip list' and check Airflow installed version. Latest version is 1.7.1.2

Comment: I'm witnessing the same issue as above. Any resolutions, been bugging me for past couple of hours.

Comment: Can you locate the airflow script in the folder python27/scripts?

Comment: I made an 'which airflow' comand and get /usr/local/bin/airflow.

Answer (score 21):

- You can create a virtual environment for Airflow to keep it as a separate entity:
  **virtualenv airflow_virtualenv**
- Go to the bin folder the virtual env:
  **cd airflow_virtualenv/bin**
- Activate the virtual env:
  **source activate**
- Set the airflow home path:
  **export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow**
  [You can also put this statement in your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc file so that you don't have to export every time]
- Install Airflow:
  **pip install apache-airflow**
  [If it throws the "six" error while installing then run: **pip install apache-airflow --ignore-installed six**]
- Initialize the database:
  **airflow initdb**
- Start the webserver: 
  **airflow webserver -p 8080**
- View the Airflow UI: 
  **http://localhost:8080/**

Comment: best way to install it nowadays (2018) is via 
`pipenv install apache-airflow`

Notice that the package name has changed. Pipenv will create a virtual environment if there is none in your current folder.

Comment: agree with @WilliMüller . I was not able to make it work without virtual environment. Using pipenv is the solution

Comment: Updated the package name to apache-airflow as the name got changed

Comment: Short working demo of the installation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFNGh86w0yM&t

Answer (score 8):

I tried both pip install apache-airflow and pip3 install apache airflow and both had issues because it installed everything in ~/.local/bin/

If you get the error that you cannot run airflow, you will find it in `~/.local/bin/airflow`. Then you can add the alias to your .bashrc: 
`alias airflow='~/.local/bin/airflow'`
then run `bash`
and you will be able to run airflow.

Then when you try to run the webserver with either the python2 or python3 version it will throw an error because it cannot find gunicorn, and you can fix that by adding ~/.local/bin to the PATH:

`export PATH=$PATH:~/.local/bin`

Answer (score 5):

Your steps look correct, if you haven't omitted anything else. But you could try Python [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) and [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) with following steps to have an isolated [airflow](/questions/tagged/airflow) environment.

```
pip install virtualenv
pip install virtualenvwrapper
# update and source your .profile
mkvirtualenv airflow
workon airflow
export AIRFLOW_VERSION=1.7.0
pip install airflow==${AIRFLOW_VERSION}
# optionally other modules
#pip install airflow[celery]==${AIRFLOW_VERSION}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using Python 3.6

```
export AIRFLOW_HOME="/Users/your_user_name/airflow"
export SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes
brew install python python3
pip install -U apache-airflow[celery,s3,postgres,jdbc,mysql,gcp_api,crypto,kubernetes]
```

Using Python 3.7 
There are some issues during installing about

> `from tenacity.async import AsyncRetrying`

Airflow worked with Python 3.7, so there is one PR on incubating side,
just need to bump up a version for a dependency name `tenacity`:
http://mail-archives.apache.org/mod_mbox/airflow-commits/201808.mbox/%3CJIRA.13177795.1533763090000.42816.1533763380326@Atlassian.JIRA%3E
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-2876
`pip install tenacity==4.12.0`

Now run Ariflow:

```
airflow initdb
airflow webserver
```

Verify the app is running in the browser by visiting http://localhost:8080.

Then run:

`airflow scheduler`

Comment: Any updates on `Python 3.7.x` compatibility? [AIRFLOW-2716](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/AIRFLOW-2716) is marked as **resolved**;  [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/CHANGELOG.txt) also indicates the same

Comment: Although [PyPi page](https://pypi.org/project/apache-airflow/) still says only till `Python 3.5.x`, while I've been using it with `Python 3.6.6` / `Python 3.6.7` for a while

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps I followed to install Airflow:

## Set the airflow home in ~/.bashrc

```
export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow
```

## Install from pypi using pip

```
pip install airflow
```

## initialising the metadata DB

```
airflow initdb
```

## starting the webserver

```
airflow webserver -p 8080
```

## open browser and go to localhost:8080 to view and use UI

Comment: Don't forget to start the scheduler as well.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the above commands, you might have to start the scheduler to allow running of jobs. The command is,

airflow scheduler

Answer (score 2):

This seems like the path to airflow is not in your PATH. does this happen with other python packages?

try:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/
```

this is the default path for airflow and should make it work

Comment: This was my issue.

Answer (score 0):

The solution the worked for was to create an environment, install airflow and then was able to run it.

-> Install virtualenv: `$pip install virtualenv`

-> Create environment: `$python -m venv myvenv`

-> Activate environment: `$source myenv/bin/activate`

-> Install airflow : `(myenv)$pip install airflow` with postgres: `pip install airflow[postgres]`

->Start the server: `(myenv)$airflow webserver -p 8080`

Answer (score 0):

An important addition to all posts.

Apache Airflow changes its package name from airflow to apache-airflow. So all posts in this thread would install Apache Airflow 1.8 as this package still exists.

To install a later version

```
export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow
pip install apache-airflow
```

Also consider which Python version to take. You may install airflow with Python 2 or Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of answers and no one mentioned containers. From my perspective airflow in docker, it's much easier, especially for development. Here is probably the best [project](https://github.com/bitnami/bitnami-docker-airflow) which supports airflow docker containers.

Here is an example of docker-compose you can take as an example:

```
version: '2'
services:
  postgresql:
    image: bitnami/postgresql:latest
    volumes:
      - postgresql_data:/bitnami/postgresql
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 5432:5432
  redis:
    image: bitnami/redis:latest
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - redis_data:/bitnami
  airflow-worker:
    image: bitnami/airflow-worker:latest
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/bitnami/airflow/dags
      - ./plugins:/opt/bitnami/airflow/plugins
  airflow-scheduler:
    image: bitnami/airflow-scheduler:latest
    depends_on:
      - redis
    env_file:
      - .env
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/bitnami/airflow/dags
      - ./plugins:/opt/bitnami/airflow/plugins
  airflow:
    image: bitnami/airflow:latest
    depends_on:
      - postgresql
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./dags:/opt/bitnami/airflow/dags
      - ./plugins:/opt/bitnami/airflow/plugins
volumes:
  postgresql_data:
    driver: local
  redis_data:
    driver: local
```

And corresponding *.env* file:

```
AIRFLOW_EXECUTOR=CeleryExecutor
AIRFLOW_PASSWORD=admin
AIRFLOW_USERNAME=admin
LOAD_EXAMPLES=no

ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
AIRFLOW__CORE__FERNET_KEY=46BKJoQYlPPOexq0OhDZnIlNepKFf87WFwLbfzqDDho=
AIRFLOW__CORE__DAG_DISCOVERY_SAFE_MODE=false
POSTGRESQL_DATABASE=bitnami_airflow
POSTGRESQL_USERNAME=bn_airflow
POSTGRESQL_PASSWORD=bitnami1
```

Regarding the [plugins](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/stable/plugins.html) dir, it's reserved directory where you can place your custom scripts/lib etc. and airflow will automatically pick them up.

Answer (score 0):

I have macOs Mojave. Airflow comes with default sqlite db which doesnt allow parallel processing. Installation is difficult.

```
brew install autoconf
brew install automake
brew install pkg-config
brew install libtool
```

Then create a virtual env for python3.7.
In venv type :

`pip install "apache-airflow[celery, crypto, postgres, rabbitmq, redis]==1.10.6"`

Airflow will be generally installed at

`‘/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/airflow’`

add this path to your path variable as shown here [Link](https://www.architectryan.com/2012/10/02/add-to-the-path-on-mac-os-x-mountain-lion/)

now type following in you virtual env that you created above for airflow.

`airflow initdb`

If this works you have installed airflow successfully.

Answer (score -1):

It worked for me :

$SLUGIFY_USES_TEXT_UNIDECODE=yes pip3 install apache-airflow

Comment: please explain your answere.