# Unable to make airflow run on Linux server

Tags: linux, centos, airflow

I installed airflow on linux server using: `sudo pip3 install apache-airflow`. It got installed successfully.

Then I did: `export AIRFLOW_HOME=~/airflow`. Finally I ran `sudo airflow initdb`, it's giving me an error:

> sudo: airflow: command not found

`echo $PATH` prints something like this:

```
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/home/xyz/abc/.local/bin:/home/xyz/abc/bin
```

I went through these posts:

[Getting bash: airflow: command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51122849/getting-bash-airflow-command-not-found)

[How to install airflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37048856/how-to-install-airflow)

But, couldn't find any solution that would solve my problem. Don't know what I'm missing. Any help regarding this would be appreciated..

Comment: Where did pip install Airflow? Normally you do not need sudo to run `airflow initdb`.

Comment: I guess it got installed in `/usr/local/bin`. That's what  I tried `sudo airflow initdb`. It gives `sudo: airflow: command not found`

Comment: Is there the Airflow binary in `/usr/local/bin`? Try `airflow initdb` without `sudo`.

Comment: Yes, it's there. Without `sudo` it prints: `-bash: /usr/local/bin/airflow: Permission denied`

Comment: What does `sudo echo $PATH` output?

Comment: It's the same that I posted in my question

Comment: `sudo /usr/local/bin/airflow initdb`?

Comment: `sudo: /usr/local/bin/airflow: command not found`

Comment: It looks like the problem is with sudo and not with Airflow. Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/18560604/6942134
Another possibility is that the executable bit is not set on `/usr/local/bin/airflow`. What does `ls -l /usr/local/bin/airflow` output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the execution bit was not set for the airflow binary. Run `sudo chmod 775 /usr/local/bin/airflow` to fix this.

Comment: airflow in bin folder didn't have executable permission. I tried this, still getting `sudo: airflow: command not found`

Comment: `airflow initdb` working now without `sudo`. But giving `airflow initdbTraceback (most recent call last):  File "/usr/local/bin/airflow", line 23, in <module>    import argcompleteModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'argcomplete'`

Comment: I think the Airflow installation is broken. It is generally not recommended to do `sudo pip install ...`. You can try installing it in a Python virtual environment.

Comment: Now, from virtual environment when I do `airflow initdb` I'm getting `File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 23, in <module>    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>    from _sqlite3 import *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_sqlite3'`

Comment: Yes, had to install `sqlite-devel` and then recompile python.